# bootstrap spacing items in div

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

[image]

Hello I would like to know how I could get my value 2 next to my value 1 with a little spacing and how I could set my text ilipsum according to the size of my button

my code:

a

```
    <div className=" col-md-6"> Image Preview</div>


    <div className=" col-md-6 ">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
                <div class="">
                    <h4>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h4>
                    <p>Cód (000000000003044425)</p>
                    <div class="values">
                        <h1>VALUE 1</h1>
                        <p>VALUE 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button className="mt-3 filterbt btn btn-outline-success waves-effect"> Comprar</button>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get "Value 1" and "Value 2" to display side by side? If so, they are inherently block level elements which is why they are currently vertical.

Comment: Yes i want for them vertically

In case I have to create a div for the tags?

Comment: My apoligies, I am a bit confused here. Can you elaborate just a bit more? If you want them side by side you can create another row within the container perhaps with sum of 12 divs that contain each block level element. 

Do you want....

Value1 | Value2

or....

Value1
Value2
?

Comment: Comments don't retain formatting.....Good to know haha.

Comment: Want to create a fiddle and go from there?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uog7jbq3/

Comment: Yes i need the vertical values

value 1 l value 2

Comment: But may I manipulate the space between them

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/36ogc4wy/

Comment: i need this: https://jsfiddle.net/b6e85m40/ but i want put  space on elements value 1 and value 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203638/discussion-between-tim-wilson-and-gabriel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display : inline` property to both element like this

```
.values h1, .values p {
    display: inline;
}

.values p{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbu3n465/)

Comment: but how can i add a space between them?

they stick together

Comment: add margin-left .. see my edi t